# How to provide filled places in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, flutter-provider, sqflite

First I want to introduce the pages.

### Form Page

This is where I fill a form. When I click save as draft it will save the form data to the SQLite database. For now, I haven't implemented SQLite yet. Anyway, But I have a list that buffers the form input. When you click on `Save as draft`, I create a `FormData` object and add that data to a list and provide that list with `Provider`.

[image: Form Page View]

### Form Page Code

```
 class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FormData? formData = FormData();
  FormPage({Key? key, this.formData}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<FormPage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<FormPage> {
  String? isEmpty(String val) {
    String? text;
    setState(() {
      if (val.isEmpty) {
        text = 'Boş bırakılamaz';
      }
    });
    return text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffe0b2),
      appBar: AppBar(
        //  backgroundColor: Colors.teal.shade400,
        title: const Text('Hasta Etkileşim Kaydı'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffb74d),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: readJsonData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var items = snapshot.data as List<dynamic>;
                  var listStajTuru = items[0].stajTuruItems;
                  var listCinsiyet = items[0].cinsiyetItems;
                  var listEtkilesim = items[0].etkilesimTuruItems;
                  var listKapsam = items[0].kapsamItems;
                  var listOrtam = items[0].ortamItems;
                  var listDoktor = items[0].doktorItems;
                  return Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        myDropDownContainer(_valueStajTuru, listStajTuru,
                            hintTextStajTuru, onChangedStajTuru),
                        myDropDownContainer(_valueDoktor, listDoktor,
                            hintTextDoktor, onChangedDoktor),
                        myDropDownContainer(_valueCinsiyet, listCinsiyet,
                            hintTextCinsiyet, onChangedCinsiyet),
                        myDropDownContainer(_valueEtkilesim, listEtkilesim,
                            hintTextEtkilesim, onChangedEtkilesim),
                        myDropDownContainer(_valueKapsam, listKapsam,
                            hintTextKapsam, onChangedKapsam),
                        myDropDownContainer(_valueOrtam, listOrtam,
                            hintTextOrtam, onChangedOrtam),
                        myTextFieldRow(20, "Kayıt No: ", 10,
                            _formData.setKayitNo, isEmpty),
                        myTextFieldRow(
                            20, "Hastanın Yaşı:", 3, _formData.setYas, isEmpty),
                        myTextFieldRow(
                            20, "Şikayet:", 10, _formData.setSikayet, isEmpty),
                        myTextFieldRow(50, "Ayırıcı Tanı:", 50,
                            _formData.setAyiriciTani, isEmpty),
                        myTextFieldRow(50, "Kesin Tanı:", 50,
                            _formData.setKesinTani, isEmpty),
                        myTextFieldRow(50, "Tedavi Yöntemi:", 100,
                            _formData.setTedaviYontemi, isEmpty),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            submitButton(context, "Sava as Draft"),
                            submitButton(context, "GÖNDER"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              })),
    );
  }

  //Kullanıcı kaydet butonuna basarsa local olarak kaydedecek

  Container submitButton(BuildContext context, String title) {
    return Container(
      width: 120,
      height: 50,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                Provider.of<FormAdd>(context, listen: false)
                  .addNewFormToList(_formData);
              alertDialog(context).then((_) =>_formKey.currentState!.reset());
            }
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: kTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
            const Color(0xffffa726),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//DropDownWidget
  Container myDropDownContainer(String initialVal, List<String> listItems,
      String text, Function myFunc) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 120,
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: kTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                //    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                //menuMaxHeight: 300,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "485s4a8sd4as85";
                  }
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                isExpanded: true,
                //onTap: () => myFunc,
                //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                value: initialVal,
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_downward,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                dropdownColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                style: kTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                onChanged: (val) => myFunc(val),
                items: listItems.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String? val) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    //TODO: Set default values
                    value: val == null ? val = initialVal : val = val,
                    child: Text(
                      val,
                      style: kTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //TextFieldWidget
  Row myTextFieldRow(double height, String text, int? maxLength,
      Function function, Function regexFunction) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 80,
          height: height,
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: kTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black54),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TextFormField(
            validator: (value) => regexFunction(value),
         //   focusNode: FocusNode(),
            onChanged: (input) {
              function(input);
            },
            autofocus: false,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
            style: kTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
            maxLength: maxLength,
            maxLines: null, //TODO:Arrange maxlines for the inputs
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, height),
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3))),
              // labelStyle:kTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white54),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<List<FormContent>> readJsonData() async {
    final jsonData =
        await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/formdata.json');
    return [
      for (final e in json.decode(jsonData)) FormContent.fromJson(e),
    ];
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FormData _formData = FormData();
  String _valueEtkilesim = "Gözlem";
  String _valueKapsam = "Öykü";
  String _valueOrtam = "Poliklinik";
  String _valueDoktor = "Diğer";
  String _valueStajTuru = "Ortopedi";
  String _valueCinsiyet = "Erkek"; // initial value
  final String hintTextCinsiyet = "Cinsiyet:";
  final String hintTextStajTuru = "Staj Türü:";
  final String hintTextEtkilesim = "Etkileşim Türü:";
  final String hintTextKapsam = "Kapsam:";
  final String hintTextOrtam = "Gerçekleştiği Ortam:";
  final String hintTextDoktor = "Klinik Eğitici:";

  void onChangedCinsiyet(String? newVal) {
    setState(() {
        _valueCinsiyet = newVal!;
        _formData.setCinsiyet(_valueCinsiyet);
    });
  }

  void onChangedStajTuru(String newVal) {
    setState(() {
      _valueStajTuru = newVal;
      _formData.setStajTuru(newVal);
    });
  }

  void onChangedEtkilesim(String newVal) {
    setState(() {
      _valueEtkilesim = newVal;
      _formData.setEtkilesimTuru(newVal);
    });
  }

  void onChangedKapsam(String newVal) {
    setState(() {
      _valueKapsam = newVal;
      _formData.setKapsam(newVal);
    });
  }

  void onChangedOrtam(String newVal) {
    setState(() {
      _valueOrtam = newVal;
      _formData.setOrtam(newVal);
    });
  }

  void onChangedDoktor(String newVal) {
    setState(() {
      _valueDoktor = newVal;
      _formData.setDoktor(newVal);
    });
  }
}
```

Assume, we saved the form as a draft. Now, It is in the DraftsPage.

### Drafts Page

Everything is alright up to now. I have a list of the saved in draft forms. When I click on any list item I could get the form information (3rd picture).
Here is the question.
When I click on the `Edit` button. I want to renavigate to the `Form Page`.However this time I want to fill the places with the relevant data. For instance, this time `Kayıt No:` TextField shouldn't be empty it must be filled with `555`, because it was saved to draft. And unfilled places must be blank. I know I need to provide an object of the form(`formData`) but, I couldn't manage it. When I click on the `Edit` button. I should provide that object and use it in the Form Page to fill those forms. But, how?

[image: Draft Page]

### Draft Code

```
class Drafts extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void pushToFormPage(FormData formData) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FormView(
                    formData: formData,
                  )));
    }

    List<FormData> _forms = Provider.of<FormAdd>(context).getForms();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Taslaklar"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(
          height: 5,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        itemCount: _forms.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return studentListViewInstanceContainer(
              const Color.fromARGB(200, 200, 130, 240),
              pushToFormPage,
              _forms[index], context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

GestureDetector studentListViewInstanceContainer(
    Color color, Function function, FormData formData,BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => function(formData),
    child: Container(
      height: 100,
      color: color,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Kayıt No: ${formData.getKayitNo()}',
                style: kTextStyle,
              ),
              Text(
                'Tarih: ${formData.getKayitNo()}',
                style: kTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 15),
              ) //TODO: implement DateT

            ],
          ),

          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                // taslağa kaydedilmiş bilgiler tekrar yüklenecek.
              FormData data=  Provider.of<FormData>(context,listen: false);
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>FormPage(formData: data,)));
              },
                child:const Text('Edit'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 5,),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

              },
                child: const Text('Delete'),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: 3rd Picture]

This is my `FormData` model class.

```
class FormData  with ChangeNotifier{
   String? _kayitNo;
   String? _stajTuru;
   String? _doktor; //TODO: Convert string to AttendingPhysician type object
  // late AttendingPhysician klinikEgitici;
   String? _yas; // TODO: Convert to string later
   String? _cinsiyet;
   String? _sikayet;
   String? _ayiriciTani;
   String? _kesinTani;
   String? _tedaviYontemi;
   String? _etkilesimTuru;
   String? _kapsam;
   String? _gerceklestigiOrtam;
  //DateTime tarih;

    String getKayitNo()=>_kayitNo!;
    String getStajTuru()=>_stajTuru!;
    String getDoktor()=>_doktor!;
    String getYas()=>_yas!;
    String getCinsiyet()=>_cinsiyet!;
    String getSikayet()=>_sikayet!;
    String getAyiriciTani()=>_ayiriciTani!;
    String getKesinTani()=>_kesinTani!;
    String getTedaviYontemi()=>_tedaviYontemi!;
    String getEtkilesimTuru()=>_etkilesimTuru!;
    String getKapsam()=>_kapsam!;
    String getOrtam()=>_gerceklestigiOrtam!;
  void setStajTuru(String stajTuru) {
    _stajTuru = stajTuru;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCinsiyet(String cinsiyet) {
    _cinsiyet = cinsiyet;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setEtkilesimTuru(String etkilesim) {
    _etkilesimTuru = etkilesim;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setKapsam(String kapsam) {
    _kapsam = kapsam;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setOrtam(String ortam) {
    _gerceklestigiOrtam = ortam;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setKayitNo(String kayitNo) {
    _kayitNo = kayitNo;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setYas(String yas) {
    _yas = yas;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setSikayet(String sikayet) {
    _sikayet = sikayet;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setAyiriciTani(String ayiriciTani) {
    _ayiriciTani = ayiriciTani;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setKesinTani(String kesinTani) {
    _kesinTani = kesinTani;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTedaviYontemi(String tedaviYontemi) {
    _tedaviYontemi = tedaviYontemi;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void setDoktor(String doktor){
    _doktor=doktor;
    notifyListeners();

  }
}
```

To make it easier to understand the question. This process is the same as saving mail as a draft. When you want to edit the mail, the unfinished mail will show up not an empty mail.